# Chart.js how to show just last 10 points in the chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I have line chart and method that is filling it with data, but i want to display only last 10 points in the chart.

```
getRandomInt() {
this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      chartData: {
        ...prevState.chartData,
        labels: [
          ...prevState.chartData.labels,
          prevState.chartData.labels.length + 1,
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            ...prevState.chartData.datasets[0],
            data: [
              ...prevState.chartData.datasets[0].data,
              Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  });
}, 2000);}
```

Is there a weay to do it?

Comment: You could use `data: [ ... ].slice(-10)` to give the last 10 elements of the array to the `data` property.

Comment: Thats how i end up doing it at the end. I was hoping there is a way of doing it in Chartjs options.